# How to clear all Vuex 4 states on logout?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuejs3, vuex4

Is there a way to clear all Vuex 4 states?

Code from `store.ts`:

```js
export const store = createStore<Record<string, any>>({
  strict: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development',
  plugins: [
    createPersistedState({
      storage: {
        getItem: k => secureLS.get(k),
        setItem: (k, v) => secureLS.set(k, v),
        removeItem: k => secureLS.remove(k),
      },
    }),
  ],
  mutations: {},
  actions: {},
  modules: {
    user,
  },
})
```

Comment: This https://github.com/robinvdvleuten/vuex-persistedstate/issues/88 would help

Comment: If you're not using a Vuex plugin for persisted storage - you can simply do a `window.location.reload()`, otherwise you will need a plugin - https://github.com/ianwalter/vuex-reset

Comment: @IVOGELOV unfortunately, that plugin doesn't support Vuex 4 yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[vuex-extensions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuex-extensions) now supports Vuex 4.

Creating store:

```js
import { Store } from 'vuex'
import { createStore } from 'vuex-extensions'

export default createStore(Store, {...})
```

Clearing store states:

```js
// Composition API
useStore().reset()

// Option API
this.$store.reset()
```